# Blank UITableView inside UIScrollView inside a UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

I am creating an App with following design:

I have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCell.
Each UITableViewCell contains a scroll view with multiple UIViews of size 150x150
Each of the small UIView contains a UITableView.

Since i am new to this, the forum is not allowing me to upload a picture, which could have explained the design very easily.

I have created the full design in the storyboard. The issue i am having is that the inner UITableView is not getting populated. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `numberOfSections` or the `numberOfRowsInSection` methods of the datasource table view controller class do not get called.

I am using XCode 4.3.2 iOS5.

Following are the class structure:

- NewsTableViewController : The ViewController for the mail table.
- NewsTableViewCell : Custom TableViewCell which contains object of custom UIScrollView.
- NewsScrollView: Custom UIScrollView containing UIViews and UITableView objects which are linked to the Storyboard UITableViews inside the UIViews.
- NewsInnerTableViewController : TableViewController to be used as Datasource and Delegate for InnerTableViews.

I have created the object of NewsInnerTableViewController in NewsTableViewController and assigned it as delegate and datasource of the inner tableview.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSSTring *CellIdentifier = @"NewCell"
    NewsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    newsInnerTableController = [[NewsInnerTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    cell.scrollView.innerTable.delegate = newsInnerTableController;
    cell.scrollView.innerTable.datasource = newsInnerTableController;

    return cell;
}
```

I am unable to understand where i am going wrong. or is something like this needs to be created is some other way. or the Datasource and delegate needs to be assigned at some other level.

Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: Found an article explaining about UITableView inside UITableViewCell. Guess this might help me with what i am trying. The tutorial is basic, but i guess this can be extended to get a what i am trying to achieve.

http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/adding-a-uitableview-inside-a-uitableviewcell/

Comment: Yup its working...the trick was to have the UITableTableViewCell as the Datasource and delegate for the inner UITableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trick is to have the UITableTableViewCell as the Datasource and delegate for the inner UITableView

http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/adding-a-uitableview-inside-a-uitableviewcell/